# How to use latest version of chromium driver with alpine

Tags: dockerfile, chromium, watir, alpine-linux

We are using Alpine for our docker container that runs our watir tests.  I would like to use a newer version like chromium75.0.3770.8 and chromium-chromedriver75.0.3770.8 instead but Alpine latest version is 73.

I have searched and searched and can not find what I need.

This is my last attempt below still uses the chrome=73.0.3683.103 and chromedriver=73.0.3683.103 when you run the tests in the container.

```
FROM ruby:alpine3.10
LABEL maintainer=""

RUN apk add --update alpine-sdk

RUN echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    chromium>75.0.3770.8 \
    chromium-chromedriver>75.0.3770.8

RUN echo "gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc" > ~/.gemrc \
 && gem install bundler

ADD ./Gemfile /Gemfile
ADD ./Gemfile.lock /Gemfile.lock

RUN bundle install

ADD ./spec /spec

CMD [“rspec”]
```

Has anyone tried to do the same and how did you to accomplish it?

Comment: Since Alpine latest is indeed 73.0.3683.103-r0, you won't find any newer version of chromium-chromedriver in the Alpine repos. Also, I'm not sure if there are Alpine Chromium binaries outside of the Alpine repos. If you must use 75.0, you'll probably have to build it from source.