# Unable to install latest version of chromium and chromium-chromedriver on linux (alpine3.9 docker image)

Tags: linux, docker, chromium, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

Trying to install latest version chromium and chromium-chromedriver on a python:alpine3.9 docker image. However it is installing old version. Not sure how to fix this. Please help.

Commands:

```
RUN apk add --update chromium>90.0.4430.24
RUN apk add --update chromium-chromedriver>90.0.4430.24
```

Below is the version that got installed.

```
bash-4.4# chromium-browser --version
Chromium 72.0.3626.121
```

Linux information:

```
bash-4.4# uname -a
Linux 53f30508846d 4.19.76-linuxkit #1 SMP Tue May 26 11:42:35 UTC 2020 x86_64 Linux
```

Below is the complete Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:alpine3.9
  
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache bash \
    alsa-lib \
    at-spi2-atk \
    atk \
    cairo \
    cups-libs \
    dbus-libs \
    eudev-libs \
    expat \
    flac \
    gdk-pixbuf \
    glib \
    libgcc \
    libjpeg-turbo \
    libpng \
    libwebp \
    libx11 \
    libxcomposite \
    libxdamage \
    libxext \
    libxfixes \
    tzdata \
    libexif \
    udev \
    xvfb \
    zlib-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    /usr/share/man \
    /tmp/*

RUN apk add --update chromium>90.0.4430.24
RUN apk add --update chromium-chromedriver>90.0.4430.24

RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" > /etc/apk/repositories \
    && echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories

#RUN apk add --update py3-pip
RUN pip3 install -U selenium --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
RUN mkdir -p /data && adduser -D chrome \
    && chown -R chrome:chrome /data
```

Comment: Can you add your Dockerfile so that people can try it?

Comment: Thank @Robert for you quick response. I have update the Dockerfile. Please have a look.

Comment: This is answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56992154/how-to-use-latest-version-of-chromium-driver-with-alpine